# How To Extract JSON Key from Computed Result in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

Hi I have a problem in Vue Js. I want to extract some Json Keys to Data Properties to post into backend using axios.

But when I do it seems failed.

Here is my code:

```
Method() {
  post_tamu(){
            this.$store.dispatch("POST_TAMU", {
                tamu: {
                    Nama: this.nama_tamu,
                    NoIdentitas: this.no_identitas,
                    NoKontak: this.no_handphone,
                    Instansi: this.instansi,
                    fotodiri: this.pict_self,
                    fotoid: this.pict_id
                },
                karyawan: {
                           Nama = this.select_karyawan.Nama,
                           NoKontak = this.select_karyawan.NoKontak,
                           },
                keperluan: this.activity,
                SIK: this.sik,
                NDA: this.NDA,
                CRQ: this.crq,
                status: false
            }).then(success => {
            this.$router.push('/')
            }).catch(error => {
                this.error = true;
            })
        },
}

Computed() {
 select_karyawan() {
            return this.LIST_KARYAWAN.filter(i => {
                return this.karyawan === "" || i.Nama == this.karyawan;
            // console.log(karyawan)
            });
        },
}
```

I think I did wrong in **this.select_karyawan.Nama** I dont have any idea to extract keys json value from computed properties.

Comment: You should have `methods: { ... }` and `computed: { ... }` (all lowercase and plain objects, not functions)

Comment: Your `select_karyawan` computed property looks to be returning an array so you'll either need to iterate it or use indexes, eg `this.select_karyawan[0].Nama`